# Flutter populate dropdownmenu with JSON

Tags: flutter

I am trying to take JSON returned from rest api and populate a dropdownmenu, I need to have the value different from the child value.  Has anyone done this or have an example or advice.  I am using the basic example and can not seem to find a way to use JSON instead of static list. Below is what I have tried and it still does not find the value.  I keep getting a dart null error.  Any help would be great. I have updated with how I get the JSON and decode.  I have tried several things. This is the error as well, but I have confirmed in debug that the value is never null, so it has to be something with the JSON.  I have tried with a static list and it works.

```
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 433 pos 15: 'value == null

String _referPractice = '<New>';
```

JSON looks like this:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"<New>"},{"id":1,"name":"Test Practice"}]


var http = createHttpClient();
var response = await http.get(_url);
var practices = await jsonCodec.decode(response.body);
practicelist = await practices.toList();

new DropdownButton<String>(
        value: _referPractice,
        isDense: true,
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            _referPractice = newValue;
          });
        },
        items: practicelist.map((value) {
          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value['id'].toString(),
            child: new Text(value['name']),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
```

Comment: Where do you get the null error? how exactly did you decoded the JSON file into your app ?

Comment: what is in `_referPractice` initially ?  and how is `practices` map  structured ?

Comment: The JSON you provided represents which variable in your code ?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to make the value be the id (value: value['id'].toString()) and the child be a text of the name(child: new Text(value['name']),) so that I can pass the id in a call later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are initializing `_referPractice` with a value that `!null`, and you are feeding it to the property `value` of the `DropDownButton`, which represents the currently selected item, and has to be null if no item has been selected yet.

I have replicated your example using the JSON you provided:

[image]

```
String _mySelection;
  List<Map> _myJson = [{"id":0,"name":"<New>"},{"id":1,"name":"Test Practice"}];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Scaffold(
        body: new Center(
          child: new DropdownButton<String>(
            isDense: true,
            hint: new Text("Select"),
            value: _mySelection,
            onChanged: (String newValue) {

              setState(() {
                _mySelection = newValue;
              });

              print (_mySelection);
            },
            items: _myJson.map((Map map) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: map["id"].toString(),
                child: new Text(
                  map["name"],
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      );

  }
```