# How to retrieve data from phpmyadmin in dropdown form using flutter

Tags: mysql, flutter

I have to fetch data from the PHPMyAdmin and display it as a dropdown menu and I have a problem how to display the data in the dropdown menu. I want to create the registration form and get the dropdown menu list from DB.

This is my coding

```
class RegisterForm extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  RegisterFormState createState(){
    return RegisterFormState();
  }
}

class RegisterFormState extends State<RegisterForm>{
  String _mySelection;

  List data=[];

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); 

  @override
  void initState(){
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }
  void fetchData() async{
    final response = await http.get('http://10.0.2.2/Shazay/getData.php');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        data = json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
  }
```

and this is the coding for the dropdown menu:

```
new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text("Energy Bubble    ",style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,color: Colors.blue),),
                new DropdownButton(
                    items: data.map((item){
                      return new DropdownMenuItem(
                          child:new Text(item['EbName']),
                          value: item['EbName'].toString(),
                      );

                }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (newVal){
                      setState(() {
                        _mySelection=newVal;
                      });
                      },
                  value: _mySelection,
                }),
              ],
            )
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit original question is describe in Step 3** 
**revised question is previously describe in Step 2 and need further info such as JSON string format from user**

Step 1 : Get your JSON string get from mysql / PHPMyAdminservice 
Step 2 : Transfer this JSON string to List of Map 
Step 3 : convert it In items of DropdownButton which means generate DropdownMenuItem

code snippet from [Flutter populate dropdownmenu with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46625438/flutter-populate-dropdownmenu-with-json)

```
String _mySelection;
  List<Map> _myJson = [{"id":0,"name":"<New>"},{"id":1,"name":"Test Practice"}];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Scaffold(
        body: new Center(
          child: new DropdownButton<String>(
            isDense: true,
            hint: new Text("Select"),
            value: _mySelection,
            onChanged: (String newValue) {

              setState(() {
                _mySelection = newValue;
              });

              print (_mySelection);
            },
            items: _myJson.map((Map map) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: map["id"].toString(),
                child: new Text(
                  map["name"],
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      );

  }
```

Comment: I need the dropdown list from the database instead of type it in the coding.

Comment: as I mentioned in Step 2, you have to parse your json string. Could you post your json string of this line data = json.decode(response.body);

Comment: please add some comments in your original question when you revise your question, it would be easier for someone who already check your question.